# Find write statement in Fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran, stdout

I'm using Fortran for my research and sometimes, for debugging purposes, someone will insert in the code something like this:

```
write(*,*) 'Variable x:', varx
```

The problem is that sometimes it happens that we forget to remove that statement from the code and it becomes difficult to find where it is being printed. I usually can get a good idea where it is by the name 'Variable x' but it sometimes happens that that information might no be present and I just see random numbers showing up.

One can imagine that doing a grep for write(*,*) is basically useless so I was wondering if there is an efficient way of finding my culprit, like forcing every call of `write(*,*)` to print a file and line number, or tracking stdout.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you have add comment line before each  one which has a unique characteristic you could easily grep for? Alternatively, use `write(*,*) 'DEBUG LOG: ', 'Variable x:', varx` and grep for "DEBUG LOG:"?

Comment: That sounds like a very good practice but unfortunately is precisely because they are not in that I have my problem. Basically I want to find the `write(*,*)` call without changing it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel's Fortran preprocessor defines a number of macros, such as `__file__` and `__line__` which will be replaced by, respectively, the file name (as a string) and line number (as an integer) when the pre-processor runs.  For more details [consult the documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-lin/GUID-32D96484-E420-44FD-A6C5-527288AA3E58.htm).

GFortran offers similar facilities, [consult the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Perhaps your compiler offers similar capabilities.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt That's very handy. They appear to be undocumented, but I just tried them myself. I will have to incorporate them into my debug statements.

Comment: @Yossarian They are documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: I took the liberty of incorporating your hyperlink into the body of the answer.

Comment: I don't see much advantage to that vs just putting identifying strings (per mbratch's comment).  In fact i'd prefer a string to search for than know the line number, but that obviously depends on personal preference, what editor you use, etc.

Comment: This is very interesting but unfortunately doesn't quite solve my problem because I can't go to the place where the `write(*,*)` code is and insert the `__line__` macro because I actually want to find where the `write(*,*)` is. Can I tell the compiler to "insert" the line number on all calls of `write(*,*)`?

Comment: Surely you could use your favourite editor's global search and replace facilities to change `write(*,*)` to `write(*,*) '__line__', ` or something like that ?

Comment: I consider this to be a "Big and Ugly Hack" since I would be messing with my code everywhere. But since it actually works and there seems to be no other more sophisticated alternative I'll accept your answer. I'll just take the liberty to add your last comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As has been previously implied, there's no Fortran--although there may be a compiler approach---way to change the behaviour of the `write` statement as you want.  However, as your problem is more to do with handling (unintentionally produced) bad code there are options.

If you can't easily find an unwanted `write(*,*)` in your code that suggests that you have many legitimate such statements.  One solution is to reduce the count:

- use an explicit format, rather than list-directed output (`*` as the format);
- instead of `*` as the output unit, use `output_unit` from the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

[Having an explicit format for "proper" output is a good idea, anyway.]

If that fails, use your version control system to compare an old "good" version against the new "bad" version.  Perhaps even have your version control system flag/block commits with new `write(*,*)`s.

And if all that still doesn't help, then the pre-processor macros previously mentioned could be a final resort.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One of the issues is that this code is being built by several people so it's more difficult to standardize what we do and the changes might stay unnoticed for a long time. I'll wait to see if someone knows of a compiler approach.

Comment: Some would say that as you increase the number of people working on the code the need for discipline/standardization increases.

Comment: Also note that if you do get an approach you're happy with, you'll likely want to apply it to `print *, ...` also.